# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function puppeteer node js

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, node-promisify

I am stuck here for a while I didn't understand the problem. Kindly someone enlightens me on this topic. here's the code.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async() => {
    let infourl = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3';
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(infourl, { waitUntil:'networkidle2' });
    let data = await page.evaluate( () =>{
        let stats = document.querySelector('div[class="title_wrapper"]').innerText;
        return {stats};
    });
    console.log(data);
    debugger;
    await browser.close();
})();
```

here is the log::

```
internal/util.js:209
    throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'original', 'function');
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function
    at promisify (internal/util.js:209:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hadi/Desktop/datachori/node_modules/extract-zip/index.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hadi/Desktop/datachori/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/BrowserFetcher.js:25:20)
```

Comment: I updated my node version from 8.0.0 to the latest recommended 12.16.3 and then I again installed puppeteer. That worked for me. Hope this helps.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It occurred to the latest version of puppeteer.
Your scripts will work properly in the lower version.

Try this script:

```
npm i -save puppeteer@1.7.0
```

Comment: I updated my node.js version from 8.0.0 to 12.16 .3 what was recommended on the site nodejs.org and then I reinstalled puppeteer. That did the trick for me thanks a lot btw.

Comment: This produces another error 
--> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following commands

```
npm config set PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD false

npm config set ignore-scripts false
```

then:

```
npm config set ignore-scripts true
```

change the flag for the ignore-scripts back as it poses a security threat if left false

Comment: This answer doesn't help

Comment: also didn't help for me
node v14.17.1 LTS